# Spring Configuration Properties with PropertySource returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a Spring Bean with a custom configuration property called `password.properties`. In order to prevent using @Valid for every field , I'm using both @ConfigurationProperties (for loading the property values into fields) and @PropertySource (for loading a custom properties file)

However, the fields are all nulls. I've generated the setters, getters and I've also tried generating a default no-argument constructor, as well as one with all argumets. What could be causing this problem?

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@PropertySource("classpath:password.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
@Setter
@Validated
@Log4j2
public class PasswordConfig {

    @Min(1)
    private Integer minLength;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer maxLength;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer characterDigitMin;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer characterLowercaseMin;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer characterUppercaseMin;
    @Min(1)
    private Integer characterSpecialMin;

    @Bean
    public PasswordValidator passwordValidator() throws IOException {
        log.debug("Password validator [LENGTH: {}-{}, NUMBERS: {}, LOWERCASE: {}, UPPERCASE: {}, SPECIAL: {}]", minLength,
                maxLength, characterDigitMin, characterLowercaseMin, characterUppercaseMin, characterSpecialMin
        );

        return new PasswordValidator(List.of(
                new LengthRule(minLength, maxLength),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit, characterDigitMin),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase, characterLowercaseMin),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase, characterUppercaseMin),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special, characterSpecialMin),
                new WhitespaceRule()
        ));
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/password.properties

```
length.max=15
length.min=5
character.digit.min=1
character.uppercase.min=1
character.lowercase.min=1
character.special.min=1
```

Main Spring Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class ReportsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReportsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error Log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordValidator' defined in class path resource [reports/config/PasswordConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.passay.PasswordValidator]: Factory method 'passwordValidator' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "reports.config.PasswordConfig.getMinLength()" is null
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.passay.PasswordValidator]: Factory method 'passwordValidator' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "reports.config.PasswordConfig.getMinLength()" is null

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "reports.config.PasswordConfig.getMinLength()" is null
    at reports.config.PasswordConfig.passwordValidator(PasswordConfig.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at reports.config.PasswordConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$passwordValidator$11(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at reports.config.PasswordConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at reports.config.PasswordConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.passwordValidator(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:141) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at reports.config.PasswordConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$3.passwordValidator(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 25 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

My Attempts:

- I tried to add @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor in the class (Failed)
- I tried to add @EnableConfigurationProperties in the class (Failed)
- I tried to add @ConfigurationPropertiesScan in the class (Failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have been close with using the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation because Spring did not know how to map the properties from your file to the class.
Have a look at the examples from [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.constructor-binding). Each dot implies the nesting of the properties.

To be able to do it you can change the `PasswordConfig` so that it corresponds with the password.properties structure:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PasswordConfig.class)
@Log4j2
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties
@Setter
@PropertySource("classpath:password.properties")
public class PasswordConfig {

    private Range length;
    private Character character;

    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class Character {
        private MinBoxed digit;
        private MinBoxed lowercase;
        private MinBoxed uppercase;
        private MinBoxed special;
    }

    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class Range {
        @Min(1)
        private Integer max;
        @Min(1)
        private Integer min;
    }

    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class MinBoxed {
        @Min(1)
        private Integer min;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordValidator passwordValidator() throws IOException {
        log.info("Password validator [LENGTH: {}-{}, NUMBERS: {}, LOWERCASE: {}, UPPERCASE: {}, SPECIAL: {}]", length.min,
                length.max, character.digit.min, character.lowercase.min, character.uppercase.min, character.special.min
        );

        return new PasswordValidator(List.of(
                new LengthRule(length.min, length.max),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit, character.digit.min),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.LowerCase, character.lowercase.min),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.UpperCase, character.uppercase.min),
                new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Special, character.special.min),
                new WhitespaceRule()
        ));
    }
}
```

Additional notes:

1. In your original snippet the `LengthRule` parameters should be flipped
2. You can use `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation istead of `@Setter`. You have to combine it with the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation. For example for the Character nested class:

```java
    @ConstructorBinding
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    static class Character {
        private MinBoxed digit;
        private MinBoxed lowercase;
        private MinBoxed uppercase;
        private MinBoxed special;
    }
```